# Trying to place a JLabel over another with image

Tags: java, jlabel

I know this question has been asked before. But mine is unique. My programing has a particular order and I'm having trouble with the JLabel with text. I need the text to remain in the center of the JFrame, but also above the image.I've tried a variety of options but nothing seems to work. Here is the relative coding:

```
public class SceneOne {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
JFrame SceneOne= new JFrame();
SceneOne.setSize(1400,700);
SceneOne.setTitle("The Car");
SceneOne.setVisible(true);
SceneOne.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
SceneOne.setLocation(500,300);





ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("/Users/computerscience2/Desktop/dark-forest-night-image.jpg"); 
JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel("", image, JLabel.CENTER); 
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
panel.add( imageLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER );
SceneOne.add(panel);
SceneOne.setResizable(true);
imageLabel.setVisible(true);
SceneOne.pack();


Button Leave=new Button("Leave");
Button Stay= new Button("Stay");
Leave.setVisible(true);
Stay.setVisible(true);
JPanel Leavebutton =new JPanel (new GridBagLayout());
Leavebutton.setVisible(true);
JPanel Staybutton=new JPanel (new GridBagLayout());
Staybutton.setVisible(true);
Leavebutton.add(Leave);
Staybutton.add(Stay);
FlowLayout two = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT);
FlowLayout three=new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT);
Leavebutton.setLayout(two);
Staybutton.setLayout(three);
SceneOne.add(Leavebutton);
SceneOne.add(Staybutton);


JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Test");
SceneOne.add(label1);


label1.setText("<html><font color='white'> It was approximately 11:30 pm. The night sky was black not a single star piercing through the darkness"
+ "except the thick and powerful moonlight." +"<br>" + "You are alone leaving a costume party at a friend's place."
+ "It was rather boring and you decided to leave early."+"A stutter is heard and your"+ "<br>"+ "car begins to shake"
+ "Your headlights and car lights crack. The engine is left dead silent." +  "You are left in a total silence"
+ "and baked in merely the moonlight." +"<br>" +  "There is a mere second of silence till a harsh chill ripes through the"
+ "car like a bullet through paper. You are left dumbfounded. What do you do?</font><html>");
label1.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    label1.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.BOTTOM);
  label1.setVisible(true);
}

}
```

Thank you in advanced

Comment: Your question is not unique, and the solution is likely the same as the others: learn how to use and then try to use the layout managers to your best advantage.

Comment: 1. Don't mix Swing and AWT components (`Button` is AWT). 2. _Please_ use Java naming convention, if not for yourself, then for us, so it easier to read. Variables begin with lower case letters 3. Use proper indentation, also, so it's easier to read

Comment: My apologize, as you can probably tell I'm new to java. I'll see if I can make this program easier to read. The buttons have been giving me problems as well.Any advice on how to not mix swing and awt while still having buttons?

Comment: um..... use `JButtons` and read the [tutorials on using Swing JButtons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html), perhaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [JLayeredPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html) for these kind of odering. It has methods like  moveToFront(Component), moveToBack(Component) and setPosition can be used to reposition a component within its layer.

```
import java.awt.ComponentOrientation;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class SceneOne extends JPanel
                 implements ActionListener {

    private JLayeredPane layeredPane;
    private JLabel imageLabel;
    int frameWidth,frameHeight;
    Rectangle bounds;

    public SceneOne()    {
    setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

    //Set the width of the frame here. It could be changes to the image width.
    frameWidth = 1400;
    frameHeight = 700;
    bounds = new Rectangle(0, 0, frameWidth, frameHeight);

    final ImageIcon bgImage = new ImageIcon("/Users/computerscience2/Desktop/dark-forest-night-image.jpg");
    imageLabel = new JLabel(bgImage);
    if (bgImage != null) {
        imageLabel.setBounds(0, 0,
                bgImage.getIconWidth(),
                bgImage.getIconHeight());
    }

    //Create and set up the layered pane.
    layeredPane = new JLayeredPane();
    layeredPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(frameWidth, frameHeight));

    //The components
    JPanel buttonPanel = createButtonPanel();

    JLabel textLabel = new JLabel("Test");
    textLabel.setText("<html><font color='white'> It was approximately 11:30 pm. The night sky was black not a single star piercing through the darkness"
        + "except the thick and powerful moonlight."
        + "<br>"
        + "You are alone leaving a costume party at a friend's place."
        + "It was rather boring and you decided to leave early."
        + "A stutter is heard and your"
        + "<br>"
        + "car begins to shake"
        + "Your headlights and car lights crack. The engine is left dead silent."
        + "You are left in a total silence"
        + "and baked in merely the moonlight."
        + "<br>"
        + "There is a mere second of silence till a harsh chill ripes through the"
        + "car like a bullet through paper. You are left dumbfounded. What do you do?</font><html>");
    textLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    textLabel.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.BOTTOM);
    textLabel.setBounds(bounds);

    //Adding components in order
    layeredPane.add(imageLabel, new Integer(0));
    layeredPane.add(buttonPanel, new Integer(1));
    layeredPane.add(textLabel, new Integer(2));

    add(layeredPane);
    }

    private JPanel createButtonPanel() {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    panel.setBounds(bounds);
    panel.setOpaque(false);
    panel.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);

    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

    JButton button;
    panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;

    button = new JButton("Stay");
    c.weightx = 0.5;
    c.weighty = 1.0;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
    button.addActionListener(this);
    panel.add(button, c);

    button = new JButton("Leave");
    c.weightx = 0.5;
    c.gridx = 2;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_END;
    button.addActionListener(this);
    panel.add(button, c);

        return panel;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String cmd = e.getActionCommand();

    if ("Stay".equalsIgnoreCase(cmd)) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Stay here!!!");
    } else if ("Leave".equalsIgnoreCase(cmd)) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Bye bye!!!");
    }
    }

    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
     * this method should be invoked from the
     * event-dispatching thread.
     */
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("SceneOne");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JComponent newContentPane = new SceneOne();
    frame.setLayout(null);
    frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
    //creating and showing this application's GUI.
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
        createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but the buttons are not appearing? what can I do to fix that?

Comment: Sorry that was just an example to show how it could be done. Updated the entire program. Hope this is what you want.